# Регулярное выражение для поиска диапазона чисел в датах

Tags: регулярные-выражения

> В сообщении может содержаться дата в формате дд.мм.гггг. В заданном формате дд - целое число из диапазона от 1 до 31, мм - целое число из диапазона от 1 до 12, а гггг - целое число из диапазона от 1900 до 2012 (если какая-то часть формата нарушена, то данная подстрока в качестве даты не рассматривается). Найти все даты, которые относятся к текущему году.

У меня получилось следующее регулярное выражение:

```
[1-31]\.[1-12]\.[1900-2012]
```

Не могу понять, почему даты, соответствующие данному формату, не распознаются.

Что мне следует исправить? Что здесь не так?

Comment: К квадратных скобках указываются допустимые символы(цифры), а не числа

Comment: `[1-31]` означает с 1 по 3, т.е. 1, 2, 3 последняя 1 игнорируется так как она в наборе уже есть. в любом случае все что в квадратных скобках означает только один символ. например с 1 до 31 выражение будет таким: `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\.`  Обратите внимание на `\\` перед точкой без нее точка будет означать любой символ

Comment: спасибо, а что означает запись "0?" ?

Comment: @Gadget, `0` - символ числа, и следующим за ним знак вопроса `?` - это квантификатор, означающий ноль или одно вхождение символа или группы символов перед ним. Т.е. в случае `0?\d` под захват будут попадать цифры `0[0-9]` и `[0-9]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В квадратных скобках перечисляются допустимые символы, в т.ч. цифры, но не числа. В вашем случае выражение будет таким:

`(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\.(19\d\d|20(0\d|1[0-2]))`

Comment: спасибо большое) а можете сказать, что означает запись "0?"?

Comment: ? означает, что допустим 0 или 1 символ, указанный слева слева. Например, + означает, что допустим 1 и более символ, указанный слева, подряд. https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.91.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BD.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.8F

Answer (score 0):

С учетом комментариев Кирилла Малышева и Mike получилось исправить выражение:

```
([1-9]|([1-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))\.([1-9]|10|11|12)\.((19[0-9][0-9])|(20((0[0-9])|10|11|12)))
```

Конечно, получилось не так красиво, как Кирилла Малышева и Mike,
получилось очень длинно, но радует, что и этот вариант сработал :)

Спасибо Вам, что помогли ошибку исправить :)

Осталось понять запись, что означает запись"0?" :)

Comment: "0?" - ноль может быть а может не быть )

Answer (score 0):

Более короткая запись с `\d`:

```
(\d|([1-2]\d)|([3][0-1]))\.([1-9]|10|11|12)\.((19\d\d)|(20((0\d)|10|11|12)))
```